# Why doesn't this code work. I'm using javascript with the library p5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

So I've been watching the coding train to learn to code in javascript and I tried to copy his code but it doesn't work. I'm using brackets. Here is the episode:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBqaA7zRO58&t=0s&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA&index=26

```
let bubbles = []

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600,400) 
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let x = 10 + 30 * i
        bubbles[i] = new Bubble(x, 200, 40);
    }
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    for(let i = 0; i < bubbles.lenght; i++) {
        bubbles[i].move;
        bubbles[i].show;
    }
}

class Bubble {
    constructor(x,y,r) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.r=r;
    }
    move() {
        this.x = this.x + random(-5,5);
        this.y = this.y + random(-5,5);
    }
    show() {
        stroke(255);
        strokeWeight(4);
        noFill();
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.r * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `length` not `lenght`. Also you have to actually *call* the functions; `bubbles[i].move()` etc.

Comment: Make sure to hit F12 to open your developer tools and have your console up while you are developing.  It will often tell you about errors it encounters as a heads up to what you are doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please get into the habit of checking your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) and [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your code.

For example, I would start by printing out the values of the variables you're using. Like this:

```
console.log(bubbles.lenght);
for(let i = 0; i < bubbles.lenght; i++) {
```

You'll see that this prints out `undefined`, which will give you a hint: you've spelled `length` wrong!

After you fix that problem, you have other issues. Take these lines:

```
bubbles[i].move;
bubbles[i].show;
```

This is not how you call functions. You need `()` parentheses after the function name:

```
bubbles[i].move();
bubbles[i].show();
```

Taking a step back, you should really not be trying to copy code like this. Instead, try to start with a simple example and then [work forward in small steps](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). Then if you encounter an error, you'll know exactly which part of the code is the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot. I know those are noob errors but thats becouse im new so sorry for the trouble